# BigQuery GIS returns incorrect value

Tags: google-bigquery, gis

As per BigQuery GIS tool this latitude longitude exists in below polygon set but bigquery returns false value. Why that bigquery return false value even if co-ordinates exists in Polygon shape.

```sql
select ST_Intersects(ST_GeogPoint(-5.4554914, 50.1822663), ST_GEOGFROMGEOJSON('{"type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [[[-5.45547968622094, 50.1821045770462], [-5.455482850644401, 50.18214838546901], [-5.45548927029794, 50.182237259112135], [-5.455494166115916, 50.18230503648512], [-5.455496215232034, 50.182333404232935], [-5.455499652048061, 50.18238098305004], [-5.455500300504948, 50.182389960185276], [-5.455478842541956, 50.18238772040404], [-5.455464007321631, 50.1823860030913], [-5.455427772503666, 50.1823828539281], [-5.455387373092614, 50.18237829938783], [-5.455372531393598, 50.182376492291915], [-5.455311734130676, 50.18236885666828], [-5.455274020622166, 50.18236269270239], [-5.455273302141769, 50.18236244420612], [-5.455263815607555, 50.18235912814621], [-5.455235928203027, 50.18234934285033], [-5.455228163993944, 50.18212934102841], [-5.45547968622094, 50.1821045770462]]]}'))
```

Comment: How you know it is inside if it is actually not? please clarify!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you explain what you mean by

> As per BigQuery GIS tool this latitude longitude exists in below polygon

You can check how far the point is from polygon using `ST_Distance` function:

```
select ST_Distance(
    ST_GeogPoint(-5.4554914, 50.1822663), 
    ST_GEOGFROMGEOJSON('{"type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [[[-5.45547968622094, 50.1821045770462], [-5.455482850644401, 50.18214838546901], [-5.45548927029794, 50.182237259112135], [-5.455494166115916, 50.18230503648512], [-5.455496215232034, 50.182333404232935], [-5.455499652048061, 50.18238098305004], [-5.455500300504948, 50.182389960185276], [-5.455478842541956, 50.18238772040404], [-5.455464007321631, 50.1823860030913], [-5.455427772503666, 50.1823828539281], [-5.455387373092614, 50.18237829938783], [-5.455372531393598, 50.182376492291915], [-5.455311734130676, 50.18236885666828], [-5.455274020622166, 50.18236269270239], [-5.455273302141769, 50.18236244420612], [-5.455263815607555, 50.18235912814621], [-5.455235928203027, 50.18234934285033], [-5.455228163993944, 50.18212934102841], [-5.45547968622094, 50.1821045770462]]]}'))
```

This returns 0.00227 - or about 2 millimeters. It might appear within the polygon, but really is just a little bit outside of it.

If you want to consider such close objects as intersecting, use `ST_DWithin(g1, g2, max_distance)` condition where `max_distance` is the maximum distance between objects in meters.